# connecting pgadmin4 to the local postgresql through a unix socket

Tags: postgresql

I installed pgadmin4 following the instructions found [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/)

I'd like to connect it to the locally running postgresql service through a Unix socket

I have

```
$ sudo ls -lha /var/run/postgresql/14-main.pg_stat_tmp/
totale 0
drwxr-s--- 2 postgres postgres 40 set 20 10:51 .
drwxrwsr-x 3 postgres postgres 60 set 20 10:51 ..
```

I see an empty folder

I don't understand

is the posgres service ready to accept a connection on a unix socket ?

Or isn't it ?

How do I do this ?

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: What do you mean a Unix socket, please clarify.

Comment: I answered my question myself. But anyway, this is what I meant by "uni socket" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 97 of pg_hba.conf was unreadable

Now pgadmin4 does connect